# Is there a list of differences in the syntax to create a database with mySQL and SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, syntax, converters, create-table

I've been searching for a conversion tool or a list of things to change when switching from mySQL to SQLite. However, the conversion tools are, as far as I found, converting an already existing mySQL database to a SQLite database.

I don't have the made the mySQL database yet, I only have the create statements. So is there either a list of changes to make to the create statements, or a converter that changes the mySQL create statements to SQLite create statements?

My sql looks like this:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `pyMS` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `pyMS` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pyMS`.`msrun`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pyMS`.`msrun` (
  `msrun_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`msrun_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pyMS`.`feature`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pyMS`.`feature` (
  `feature_id` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  `intensity` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `overallquality` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `quality` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `charge` INT NOT NULL ,
  `content` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `msrun_msrun_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_id`, `msrun_msrun_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`feature_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_feature_msrun1` (`msrun_msrun_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_feature_msrun1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`msrun_msrun_id` )
    REFERENCES `pyMS`.`msrun` (`msrun_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you will find a list of changes like "replace A with B".
What you can do is look what these migration scripts do and come up with your own list.

For example, take the one on this [link](http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite)

if you get commands like `sed 's/ smallint([0-9]*) / integer /g' |` you can see what's being done (sed is a string replacement unix command).

Its just a matter of going through the scripts.